# Rome football derby - how can I visit it?

Tags: safety, activities, events, rome, football

I want to get into the Rome for the famous Rome derby, but don't know anything about possibilities of buying the ticket for foreigners, on which stadium should I watch this match and safety actions on this match.
Can you help me with that?

[image]

Comment: [Relevant meta discussion](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/119/is-a-question-about-sport-events-visiting-on-or-off-topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Derby is played at the Olympic Stadium in Rome. Tickets are hard to get, but there are sites online. See [my blog article](http://www.roninrome.com/%20entertainment/futbol-in-rome) for more information on the stadium, tickets, and brokers.